# Why lua_tonumber() has different behavior from lua_tointeger() when dealing with big integer?

Tags: c, lua

I tried to convert a string from Lua(5.1.5) to an integer, and check if the number is a valid integer(0~99999). However, I found lua_tonumber() has different behavior from lua_tointeger() when dealing with big integer.

```
int main()
{
    int in;
    double db;

    lua_State* Lua = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(Lua);

    lua_pushstring(Lua, "213232127162767162736718238168263816873");
    db = lua_tonumber(Lua, -1);
    in = lua_tointeger(Lua, -1);
    printf("DOUBLE:%f\n", db); // DOUBLE:213232127162767176000119210017101447168.000000
    printf("INT:%d\n", in);    // INT:0
};
```

If I use lua_tointeger(), it returns 0 and will pass my checking.

I check both API description, but I still don't know why they have different behaviors. Are these behaviors machine-independent? Is using lua_tonumber() a better way?

Can I use the following code to check the result? (cross-platform)

```
if (!lua_isnumber(Lua, -1)) { //error }
result = lua_tonumber(Lua, -1);
if (result < 0 || result > 99999) { // error2 }
// pass
```

Comment: Integers are 2 or 4 bytes, `double` is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual reference of [`lua_tointeger`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tointeger):

> Converts the Lua value at the given acceptable index to the signed integral type `lua_Integer`. The Lua value must be a number or a string convertible to a number (see §2.2.1); otherwise, `lua_tointeger` returns `0`

The same is with `lua_tonumber`. So when you get the return value of `0` means you are passing a string that is non-convertible. The number `213232127162767162736718238168263816873` is too big for an `lua_Integer`(the same as `ptrdiff_t` by default) type.

> Are these behaviors machine-independent? Is using lua_tonumber() a better way?

In a way, it is machine-dependent, because the type `lua_Integer` is machine-dependent. Again, the number `213232127162767162736718238168263816873` is too big for any normal integer type. Whether using `lua_tonumber` or using `lua_tointeger` is up to your need. If converting an integer that is less than 32-bit, for example, 0~99999 in your question, `lua_tointeger` is your choice. It is very fast in a IEEE-754 compatible machine. The disadvantage of using `lua_tonumber` is that it may mis-convert non-integer values.

Reference: [A fast method to round a double to a 32-bit int explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17035464/1009479)