# Can I use lua_tointeger() for off_t?

Tags: c, lua

Should I use `lua_tointeger()`, or `lua_tonumber()`, when converting Lua numbers to `off_t` values?

I checked the source code of Lua itself and I see that their [file:seek](http://devdocs.wesnoth.org/liolib_8c_source.html#l00536) function uses `lua_Number`, not `lua_Integer`.

I also see that the [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix/blob/master/ext/posix/posix.c) package uses `lua_tonumber()` (or luaL_checknumber() etc) extensively, even to read file decriptors(!).

And what about `size_t`?

Should I go to the "extreme" and use `lua_tonumber()` (and `lua_pushnumber()`) for all integral C types (mode_t, size_t, etc.)? Or should I normally use `lua_tointeger()` and resort to `lua_tonumber()` only when I "feel" it's a potentially big number?

Comment: Please, always link to the correct source. You linked to the Battle for Wesnoth code, not the [original Lua `file:seek` implementation](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/liolib.c.html#f_seek). They happen to be the same, but you never know in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build Lua yourself you can check in `luaconf.h` how lua_Number and lua_Integer are defined.
Usually lua_number is the same thing as double and lua_Integer is ptrdiff_t.

`ptrdiff_t` (usually `int32_t` or `int64_t`) is closer to `off_t` (`uint32_t` or `uint64_t`) than `double` but **Lua will probably store the number in `double` format anyway**.

On the other hand `double` can store integers precisely up to 2^52 if I remember correctly. In most cases it should be sufficient.

I would suggest using `lua_*number()` where you expect `float/double` and `lua_*integer()` when you expect integers (like all those OS related functions with FDs, offsets and positions).

Answer (score 2):

Since `off_t` and `size_t` are both integral types, you should use `lua_tointeger`.

From [the source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.c.html#lua_tointegerx), `lua_tointeger` actually gets the number as `lua_Number`, then [converts it to  `lua_Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17035464/1009479). The only concern is that `lua_Integer` may be too small, but as it's implemented as `ptrdiff_t` which in practice is usually 32-bit on 32-bit machine and 64-bit on 64-bit machine.